# ComponentArt controls are stating that they are unlicensed even though I have a valid license

Tags: c#, asp.net, componentart

I'm working on a legacy application that uses these third party controls. I'm unable to get it to run properly because the controls are showing and in the page designer, it's showing a message that states the controls are unlicensed.

[image]

I just installed all of the components, the license file is in the bin folder, and it's an x86 application.

Anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score -2):

The best will be to contact the company that sold you thouse controls, they always provide good and prompt support for such issues. Of course if you have licence ;)

Comment: I had considered this. But they're support forum only have post from this year. I was hoping to get information from others who have been through it already.